# Compose Card always overdrawn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

### Issue

Compose card surface shows always overdrawn. However, it's not the case if we use old style CardView in xml.

From [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/inspect-gpu-rendering#debug_overdraw) it's always recommended to reduce overdrawing of any view to make it more towards green, blue.

Just this following code will produce some output like this, which means it's overdrawn 3 or 4 times.

```
 Card(
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 10.dp),
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(vertical = 10.dp)
       ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(all = 16.dp)
        ) {
            Text("randomText")
        }
    }
```

[image]

I tried to look into NowInAndroid [sample application](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid) but even that produces all red output when debugged to show overdrawn areas.

[image: NowInAndroid-mainscreen]

### Question

- Is the Debug GPU Overdraw option in developer settings giving right information?
- Can we really avoid this overdraw? If so, how?

Comment: From the first screenshot, it doesn't look this this is caused by the card. The main background is green, which indicates it's already overdrawn twice. The card itself is pink, indicating three levels. In other words, the card is drawing over the background a single time, which is expected since it's not transparent. More likely you're seeing an issue of multiple full screen backgrounds such as Surface being used.

Comment: I am thinking it's green probably bcz of `Scaffold`. I am drawing this inside a lazy column. So, an item inside a lazy column holds a card.  If what you're saying is true then should we avoid using scaffold?

Comment: I would say use Scaffold if you need it (e.g., using app bars, bottom nav, etc.). Scaffold will create a Surface, so you can make it transparent if you don't need the background. That said, overdraw is far less of a problem with modern GPUs than it was in the past due to deferred rendering, improved fill rates, and bandwidth improvements. I'd recommend measuring that it is making an impact in your case before changing UI component decisions to potentially decrease overdraw. In other words, build the UI the 'right' way, then measure the performance, then go back to optimize.

Comment: What did you do to fix this?